# Delete parent if child empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I neeed to do xslt to transform this xml to another WHERE: shows only  where **effectiveDate** not empty and **ratingChar1** starting with "WL" 
 I really ot don't understand what I am doing but here is my xslt:
I neeed to do xslt to transform this xml to another WHERE: shows only  where **effectiveDate** not empty and **ratingChar1** starting with "WL" 
 I really ot don't understand what I am doing but here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="effectiveDate[not('')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="effectiveDate[@value=''] | parent[child[@value='']]" />
  <xsl:template match="ratingDataModel[descendant::ratingChar1[(starts-with(.,'WL'))]]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

And this is XML:

```
<EagleML eaglemlVersion="2-0" actualBuild="1" eaglemlType="ReferenceTransactionMessage" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
<header>
    <batchIdentifier>
        <batchId>ADX_A.20121214</batchId>
        <sequenceNumber>44</sequenceNumber>
        <totalCount>44</totalCount>
    </batchIdentifier>
    <sentBy>ALLSTATE</sentBy>
    <creationTimestamp>2012-12-14T22:33:50.816-06:00</creationTimestamp>
</header>
<validation validationScheme="Allstate" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">Allstate</validation>
<party id="Allstate" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
    <partyId>Allstate</partyId>
    <partyName>Allstate Investments</partyName>
</party>
<referenceTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="Allstate">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="Allstate">Allstate</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>ALADDIN</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ALDDNGAL</updateSource>
        <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>2</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5mbeatt</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:57:29-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>RV_2</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator/>
            <ratingChar1>RV_2</ratingChar1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</referenceTransaction>
<referenceTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="Allstate">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="Allstate">Allstate</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>ALADDIN</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ALDDNGAL</updateSource>
        <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>45</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5mbeatt</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:57:29-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>TH_45</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator/>
            <ratingChar1>TH_45</ratingChar1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</referenceTransaction>
<referenceTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="Allstate">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="Allstate">Allstate</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>ALADDIN</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ALDDNGAL</updateSource>
        <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>CONCERN</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5bprice</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:43:59-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>WL_CONCERN</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator>WATCHLIST</ratingTypeIndicator>
            <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            <ratingDate1>2012-12-14</ratingDate1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</referenceTransaction>
<referenceTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="Allstate">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="Allstate">Allstate</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>ALADDIN</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ALDDNGAL</updateSource>
        <effectiveDate></effectiveDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>CONCERN</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>nfallon</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T16:05:25-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>WL_CONCERN</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator>WATCHLIST</ratingTypeIndicator>
            <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            <ratingDate1>2012-12-14</ratingDate1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</referenceTransaction>
</EagleML>
```

Expected XML:

```
<EagleML eaglemlVersion="2-0" actualBuild="1" eaglemlType="ReferenceTransactionMessage" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
<header>
    <batchIdentifier>
        <batchId>ADX_A.20121214</batchId>
        <sequenceNumber>44</sequenceNumber>
        <totalCount>44</totalCount>
    </batchIdentifier>
    <sentBy>ALLSTATE</sentBy>
    <creationTimestamp>2012-12-14T22:33:50.816-06:00</creationTimestamp>
</header>
<validation validationScheme="Allstate" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">Allstate</validation>
<party id="Allstate" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
    <partyId>Allstate</partyId>
    <partyName>Allstate Investments</partyName>
</party>
<referenceTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="Allstate">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="Allstate">Allstate</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>ALADDIN</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ALDDNGAL</updateSource>
        <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>CONCERN</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5bprice</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:43:59-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>WL_CONCERN</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator>WATCHLIST</ratingTypeIndicator>
            <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            <ratingDate1>2012-12-14</ratingDate1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</referenceTransaction>
</EagleML>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected output in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to exclude certain `referenceTransaction` elements, you really need a template that matches `referenceTransaction`, with a condition in `[]`. In terms of the condition, you should reverse the logic. Instead of having the condition for what you want to keep, you should negate it to give the condition for which you want to remove.

```
 <xsl:template match="referenceTransaction
                      [rating/effectiveDate='' or not(starts-with(rating/ratingDataModel/ratingChar1,'WL'))]"/>
```

i.e remove `referenceTransaction` if `effectiveDate` is empty or `ratingChar1` does not start with `WL`.

However, you have a second problem. In your XML you have default namespace

```
xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0"
```

But you have not accounted for this in the XSLT. If you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xpath-default-namespace` to handle this.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="referenceTransaction[rating/effectiveDate='' or not(starts-with(rating/ratingDataModel/ratingChar1,'WL'))]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

If, however, you are using XSLT 1.0, you will have to define a namespace prefix and use that in the template match

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:eml="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="eml:referenceTransaction[eml:rating/eml:effectiveDate='' or not(starts-with(eml:rating/eml:ratingDataModel/eml:ratingChar1,'WL'))]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:referenceTransaction[normalize-space(descendant::a:effectiveDate)='' and starts-with(descendant::a:ratingChar1, 'WL')]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```